# how to dynamically fill Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: c#, database, twitter-bootstrap

i am very new to Bootstrap.i have a notification drop down that fills like

```
<!-- BEGIN NOTIFICATION DROPDOWN -->
                <li class="dropdown" id="notifications-header">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true">
                        <i class="glyph-icon flaticon-notifications"></i>
                        <span class="badge badge-danger badge-header">6</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dropdown-header clearfix">
                            <p class="pull-left">Notifications</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu-list withScroll" data-height="220">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <i class="fa fa-star p-r-10 f-18 c-orange"></i>
                                        Steve have rated your photo
                                        <span class="dropdown-time">Just now</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <i class="fa fa-heart p-r-10 f-18 c-red"></i>
                                        John added you to his favs
                                        <span class="dropdown-time">15 mins</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
```

and so on
now how can i dynamically populate this dropdown with the database?

Comment: Are you using Razor or ASPX?

Comment: i am using ASPX (asp.net 4.5)...Any startup tutorial atleast is greatly appreciated...

Comment: I do not have much experience with aspx, but I would do:

-> (Code Behind) Add a public property of type collection
-> (Code Behind) In the Page_Load event add items on the property created.
-> (Layout page) make a loop and go adding the necessary items from the public property.

Comment: Till Code behind i am agree but the with a Layout page i need to search more...:( anywayz thanks for your suggestion...i would be happy if you can   put some more sentences. :)

Comment: maybe it helps (I would do something similar on aspx): http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax

Comment: look: [How to create controls dynamically using for loop in aspx page (not in code behind)](http://forums.asp.net/p/1213487/2150945.aspx?Re+How+to+create+controls+dynamically+using+for+loop+in+aspx+page+not+in+code+behind+)

Comment: Dear Yuri...i read your links , googled a bit and able to solve my problems...thumbs up!

Comment: Please post your solution. I'm sure you can help others :)

Comment: Sorry for my late reply...oh yes why not...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer...i am just putting the mechanism of how it works...anybody can use data structure that suites them.

(1)In the database i created a simple table called "notifications" with the three fields
  (a)friend_name ; to store name of friends who message you
  (b)notifications; to store the original message
  (3)notification_time; to store the time at which one messaged you

(2) In code behind i created 3 Lists object and an integer filed to store message count

(a)friend_name ; to store name of friends who message you
  (b)notifications; to store the original message
  (c)notification_time; to store the time at which one messaged you
  (d)Count ; to store message count.
    private List friend_name = new List();
    private List notification_time = new List();
    private List notification_time = new List();

(3)Now i populate these lists in the page load which is usual for developer...
     conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=XXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXX;Integrated        Security=True");
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Select *  from notifications");
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataReader reader;
        conn.Open();
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

```
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        friend_name.Add(reader["friend_name"].ToString());
        notifications.Add(reader["notifications"].ToString());
        notification_time.Add(reader["notification_time"].ToString());
        count++;
    }
```

(4)now go to aspx file (markup) and call the three lists object like that...
    <% for (int i=0; i 
                                     
                                        
                                            
                                        
                                        
                                            
                                                **'<%=Friend_Name[i]%>'** 
                                                
                                                    '<%=Notification_Time[i]%>'

'<%=Notifications[i]%>'...

```
                                 <% } %>
```

finally you will be able to fill your bootstrap dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: I'm using your answer as a reference, and I'm making a few assumptions along the way, edit accoringly**

You have the table, and the sql query down. (You should really look into Entity Framework, rather than doing regular sql queries. Entity Framework is the new flavor when reading/saving data to a database).

You should make a new class that can contain the data from the table. Something like:

```
public class Notification
{
    public string FriendName {get;set;}
    public string Notification {get;set;}
    public DateTime Date {get;set;} // assuming you have a valid datetime that can be parsed.
}
```

In your `Page_Load` event, you would make some modifications.
Here we put all data from the reader into `Notification` objects, which we put into a `List<Notification>`, which we then at the end databind to the repeater, which would be responsible for rendering the desired output. Note: Wrapping `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlReader` in a `using()` will dispose them after use, and release the resources.

```
        string connectionString = "Data Source=XXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXX;Integrated Security=True";
        string sqlQuery = "Select * from notifications";

        List<Notification> notifications = new List<Notification>();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn))
            {
                comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                using (SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Notification notification = new Notification();
                        notification.FriendName = reader["friend_name"].ToString();
                        notification.Notification = reader["notifications"].ToString();
                        notification.Date = reader["notification_time"].ToString();

                        notifications.Add(notification);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        DropDownItems.DataSource = notifications;
        DropDownItems.DataBind();
```

The element you are asking for is the `asp:Repeater`, which you can add a `DataSource` to, and `DataBind`. To repeat the elements within the dropdown you could do this: (Note: I'm assuming that friend_name is the item name, and notification is the url.)

```
<asp:Repeater ID="DropDownItems" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="<%# Eval("Notification") %>"><%# Eval("FriendName") %></a>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

***TL;DR: Use a asp:Repeater rather than a regular for loop within the webforms markup (aspx).***

Comment: Well, your question bundled with your answer does not incorporate any javascript (other than the implied bootstrap framework), and the answer you wrote is a server side variant. FYI: `<%=Friend_Name[i]%>' '<%=Notification_Time[i]%>` which you have in your aspx, is rendered server side. The example I'm presenting is merely a refined version from your answer. asp:Repeater with a List<T> datasource is preferred over a multi list for loop with separate count variable.